# Issue In Custom ListView

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I've made a Custom ListView that shows a List of currencies with (Image + TextView + LinearLayout having to prices: 1 for sell currency & 1 for Buy it ).
But unfortunately, the app's been crashed, then I've opened LogCat to see the error,  but nothing has found.
I've attached my files to inspect. Starting  from  the next package adapters

```
package adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.aboomar.bekamelnaharda.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import models.CurrencyModel;

public class CurrencyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
ArrayList<CurrencyModel> currencyModelArrayList;
CurrencyModel currencyModel = new CurrencyModel();

public CurrencyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CurrencyModel> 
currencyModelArrayList) {
this.context = context;
this.currencyModelArrayList = currencyModelArrayList;
}

public CurrencyAdapter() {
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
return currencyModelArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public CurrencyModel getItem(int position) {
return currencyModelArrayList.get(currencyModel.getId());
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
return getItem(currencyModel.getId()).getId();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
convertView = 
layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.currency_list_item,parent,false);
currencyModel = getItem(currencyModel.getId());

ImageView imageViewCurrency = 
convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageCurrencyIv);
imageViewCurrency.setImageResource(currencyModel.getCurrencyImage());

TextView currencyNameTv = convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameCurrencyTv);
currencyNameTv.setText(currencyModel.getCurrencyTv());

TextView currencyBuyTv = convertView.findViewById(R.id.buyPriceTv);
currencyBuyTv.setText(currencyModel.getCurrencyPriceBuy());

TextView currencySellTv = convertView.findViewById(R.id.sellPriceTv);
currencySellTv.setText(currencyModel.getCurrencyPriceSell());


return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `null` in getView method but should be returning `convertView`

Comment: It's been solved, but another issue appeared after pressing one of the items, the app crash and show this error. Process: com.example.aboomar.bekamelnaharda, PID: 30648
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 7, Size: 7
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at adapters.CurrencyAdapter.getItem(CurrencyAdapter.java:38)
        at adapters.CurrencyAdapter.getItemId(CurrencyAdapter.java:43)